# Terraform Bigquery create tables replace table instead of edit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I added a json file that contains all the tables i want to create :

tables.json

```json
    "tables": {
            "table1": {
                "dataset_id": "dataset1",
                "table_id": "table1",
                "schema_path": "folder/table1.json"
            },
            "table2": {
                "dataset_id": "dataset2",
                "table_id": "table2",
                "schema_path": "folder/table2.json"
            }
    }
```

Then with a foreach on a Terraform resource, i want to create these tables dynamically :

local.tf file

```
    locals {
      tables = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/resource/tables.json"))["tables"]
    }
```

variables.tf file

```
    variable "project_id" {
      description = "Project ID, used to enforce providing a project id."
      type = string
    }
    
    variable "time_partitioning" {
      description = "Configures time-based partitioning for this table."
      type = map(string)
      default = {
        type = "DAY"
        field = "my_field"
      }
    }
```

main.tf file

```
    resource "google_bigquery_table" "tables" {
      for_each = local.tables
      project = var.project_id
      dataset_id = each.value["dataset_id"]
      table_id = each.value["table_id"]
    
      dynamic "time_partitioning" {
        for_each = [
          var.time_partitioning
        ]
        content {
          type = try(each.value["partition_type"], time_partitioning.value["type"])
          field = try(each.value["partition_field"], time_partitioning.value["field"])
          expiration_ms = try(time_partitioning.value["expiration_ms"], null)
          require_partition_filter = try(time_partitioning.value["require_partition_filter"], null)
        }
      }
    
      schema = file("${path.module}/resource/schema/${each.value["schema_path"]}")
    }
```

The schema files contains classic bigquery schema, for example :

```json
    [
        {
            "name": "field",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "description": "My field"
        }
    ]
```

The creation of tables works well, but when i add a new nullable field on a schema, Terraform proposes to "replace table" (destroy and recreate) instead of "update table".

The normal behaviour in this case for native Bigquery and Terraform is to update the table.

When a do the same test with the same Terraform resource but without forEach, Terraform has the expected behaviour and proposes to update the table.

An example of the Terraform log with "forEach" :

```
 

    # google_bigquery_table.tables["table1"] must be replaced
    -/+ resource "google_bigquery_table" "tables" {
          ~ creation_time       = 1616764894477 -> (known after apply)
            dataset_id          = "dataset1"
            deletion_protection = true
          ~ etag                = "G9qwId8jgQS8nN4N61zqcA==" -> (known after apply)
          ~ expiration_time     = 0 -> (known after apply)
          ~ id                  = "projects/my-project/datasets/dataset1/tables/table1" -> (known after apply)
          - labels              = {} -> null
          ~ last_modified_time  = 1617075251337 -> (known after apply)
          ~ location            = "EU" -> (known after apply)
          ~ num_bytes           = 0 -> (known after apply)
          ~ num_long_term_bytes = 0 -> (known after apply)
          ~ num_rows            = 0 -> (known after apply)
            project             = "project"
          ~ schema              = jsonencode(
              ~ [ # forces replacement
                    {
                        description = "Field"
                        mode        = "NULLABLE"
                        name        = "field"
                        type        = "STRING"
                    }
             
             .....
             + {
                  + description = "Field"
                  + mode        = "NULLABLE"
                  + name        = "newField"
                  + type        = "STRING"
               }
```

Terraform displays and detects correctly the new column to add for a table, but indicates a replace instead of an edition.

I repeat that, the exact same test with a the same Terraform resource without forEach and on a single Bigquery table, works well (same schema, same change). I create the table and when a add a new nullable column, Terraform proposes an edition (the expected behaviour).

I checked on Terraform doc and web, i didn't saw some examples to manage a list of table with Terraform.

Is it not possible to create and update tables with configured tables and foreach ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks so much *@Alessandro*, the problem was indeed due to the Terraform provide Google version.
I used the v3.62.0 version of Google provider, and you target me to the good direction.

I saw this link too : https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/8503

There is a very useful comment by "tpolekhin" (thanks to him) :

```
Hopefully im not beating a dead horse commenting on the closed issue, but I did some testing with various versions on the provider, and it behaves VERY differently each time.

So, our terraform code change was pretty simple: add 2 new columns to existing BigQuery table SCHEDULE
Nothing changes between runs - only provider version

v3.52.0
Plan: 0 to add, 19 to change, 0 to destroy.
Mostly adds + mode = "NULLABLE" to fields in bunch of tables, and adds 2 new fields in SCHEDULE table

v3.53.0
Plan: 0 to add, 2 to change, 0 to destroy.
Adds 2 new fields to SCHEDULE table, and moves one field in another table in a different place (sorting?)

v3.54.0
Plan: 1 to add, 1 to change, 1 to destroy.
Adds 2 new fields to SCHEDULE table, and moves one field in another table in a different place (sorting?) but now with table re-creation for some reason

v3.55.0
Plan: 0 to add, 2 to change, 0 to destroy.
Adds 2 new fields to SCHEDULE table, and moves one field in another table in a different place (sorting?)
behaves exactly like v3.53.0

v3.56.0
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

In this comment, we can see that some versions have the problem.
For example this works with v3.55.0 but not with v3.56.0

I temporary downgrade the version to v3.55.0 and when the next release will solve this issue, i will upgrade it.

provider.tf :

```
    provider "google" {
      version = "= 3.55.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This sounded like a provider bug. I found this [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/8710) in the [terraform-provider-google](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google) repository that seems related to your issue. The [fix](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/pull/8803) was merged just 13 hours ago (at the time of writing). So, maybe you can wait for the next release (`v3.63.0`) and see if it fixes your issue.

Just FYI: You might want to verify that the fix commit was actually included in the next release. It happened to me before that something that was merged in master before a released was not actually released.